# Search string in php for characters that are not

Tags: php

This is probably very simple, but I couldn't find it.

I need to search a string for a group of chinese characters, and replace them with an english word.

So basically search a string for the first character that is not a-z, 1-9 or - , but I couldn't find how.

I'm currently using string pointers at the start and end of the characters to achieve the result, which working is fine, but looking pretty sloppy.

```
   $str_start = strpos ( $switcher , 'start' );// get the string start
   $str_start +=5;//Add 5 to it to make up for the length of search term
   $str_end = strpos ( $switcher , '/' , $str_start );//find the end
   $length = $str_end - $str_start;//get the length of chinese characters
   echo substr_replace ( $switcher , 'product-category' , $str_start , $length );//replace with english word
```

EDIT: Actual example added for clarity:

```
<option value="http://imw1248.info/商品分类/bamboo-cutting-board/small-cutting-boards/">English</option>
```

Should be:

```
<option value="http://imw1248.info/product-category/bamboo-cutting-board/small-cutting-boards/">English</option>
```

Code:

```
       $str_start = strpos ( $switcher , '.info/' );
       $str_start +=6;
       $str_end = strpos ( $switcher , '/' , $str_start );
       $length = $str_end - $str_start;//get the length of chinese characters
       echo substr_replace ( $switcher , 'product-category' , $str_start , $length );
```

Comment: you need to use preg_replace() for replacing ..just go to the documentation page before asking a qus ..

Comment: A few examples of how you intend strings to appear before and after may make your intentions a bit clearer.

Comment: I do like the almost philosophical implications of the title: "Search string in php for characters that are not", "I am looking for that which is not", "I think that which I don't"

Comment: @CodeLover there is no need to use [regex replace](http://php.net/preg_replace) instead of [string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) [substitution](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) if it's not required. Simply adds extra overhead and complexity that may not be needed. Better off first scoping the requirements.

Comment: @Alex.Ritna I'll add an actual example

Comment: @Alex.Ritna but preg_replace can also solve its problem ..see his qus ..he needs to replace the match with an english word ..and i think it can be done via preg_replace too

Comment: @CodeLover, I think preg_replace() would be the best way, I didn't come up in my 'not' searches.  Working on the reg ex now.

Comment: @CodeLover That might have just been me jumping on your suggestion without explanation. While preg_replace has its uses (such as this question, now we have some more information) too often people go straight to it as a default which can cause more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To search and replace Chinese characters I usually use this regexp

```
$charFound = preg_match( '/^[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]+$/u', trim( $data["value"] ), $arrayOfCharacters );
```

This will find all Chinese characters only in the given string and return them. That is one solution to get them in a strict and validated format and also make sure your code works. You could easily extend and do more with that.

I would use http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php handling to find and replace specific sets of characters if a match is found.

Comment: That's awesome, thank you.  That will be really handy on my current project.

Comment: @cleric ...according to his question he needs to replace those chineese characters to english one right ??.so he needs to use preg_replace ...for replacing those

Comment: @Talknerdytome Happy to help, we do a lot of Chinese char stuff at my current job, and its not my native lang.

Comment: @CodeLover You are absolutely right, I gave him/her a piece of code to be able to solve the problem, not the solution to the exact problem he/she wanted to solve.

Comment: +1 for not just assuming I'm a guy.  Also, I am happy with the answer as I can use it in many situations